# how can I keep the order of row and col in a heatmap with cluster

Tags: r

I have read quite some questions and looked around to find any function in order to make a heatmap where i can keep the order of row and column the same while do the clustering . I could not find anything

```
df<- structure(c(1804L, 147L, 2982L, 263L, 1420L, 2225L, 905L, 1654L, 
2018L, 0L, 1L, 1649L, 53L, 1388L, 830L, 0L, 217L, 85L, 831L, 
15499L, 37394L, 568L, 216L, 498L, 78L, 696L, 1831L, 1098L, 3283L, 
2683L, 1L, 2L, 25896L, 114L, 2597L, 2476L, 0L, 83L, 65L, 2983L, 
62277L, 43394L, 3836L, 181L, 4565L, 460L, 4780L, 3961L, 1017L, 
691L, 2348L, 0L, 0L, 1987L, 20L, 831L, 4269L, 0L, 7L, 58L, 64L, 
1670L, 8250L, 1074L, 92L, 4804L, 141L, 1893L, 2444L, 1045L, 1314L, 
1848L, 0L, 0L, 3352L, 50L, 1396L, 11083L, 0L, 130L, 65L, 471L, 
16847L, 24535L, 2057L, 363L, 2739L, 244L, 4473L, 1581L, 1161L, 
4366L, 7743L, 0L, 0L, 4529L, 96L, 2815L, 5407L, 0L, 2451L, 273L, 
14016L, 209852L, 192321L, 791L, 140L, 434L, 143L, 1036L, 1012L, 
264L, 1279L, 987L, 0L, 0L, 4834L, 60L, 1952L, 489L, 0L, 39L, 
29L, 502L, 10482L, 17520L, 2259L, 280L, 1817L, 398L, 3318L, 2375L, 
729L, 2214L, 1601L, 0L, 0L, 5894L, 58L, 4210L, 5245L, 0L, 111L, 
206L, 1683L, 34731L, 57623L, 3868L, 309L, 5879L, 398L, 6534L, 
3191L, 2218L, 2076L, 4670L, 0L, 0L, 4089L, 49L, 1891L, 1506L, 
0L, 96L, 106L, 227L, 5869L, 5844L, 6126L, 527L, 1768L, 298L, 
7844L, 1574L, 922L, 2179L, 6217L, 0L, 0L, 2588L, 42L, 1296L, 
2163L, 0L, 2L, 48L, 129L, 3031L, 18798L, 3354L, 256L, 4796L, 
366L, 4875L, 1910L, 2200L, 3631L, 10243L, 0L, 1L, 2899L, 175L, 
1555L, 6639L, 0L, 1200L, 109L, 4801L, 67661L, 78865L, 849L, 89L, 
639L, 60L, 2623L, 368L, 444L, 823L, 994L, 0L, 0L, 3063L, 25L, 
421L, 838L, 0L, 154L, 49L, 517L, 11004L, 7515L, 2244L, 594L, 
2712L, 327L, 3178L, 5659L, 1828L, 2427L, 10729L, 0L, 0L, 5371L, 
272L, 8191L, 4524L, 0L, 207L, 146L, 4249L, 66773L, 81601L), .Dim = c(21L, 
12L), .Dimnames = list(c("A149564", "A108622", "B178878", "E163072", 
"S184113", "N159216", "G0112149", "EN183160", "EM168329", "EN232793", 
"ENS277545", "E0108691", "E0115008", "E37462", "EN0775", "E0100146", 
"E7430", "ENU653", "E00168314", "T197971", "ENSG0"), c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", 
"Sample8", "Sample9", "Sample10", "Sample11", "Sample12")))
```

They often say that I should use `Colv = NA,Rowv = NA` but this will kill the clustering. So I would like to know if there is any other way ? to plot a heatmap while keep the sample as it is ?

I want to have row names with the same order as the data input , for example like this

```
A149564
A108622
B178878
E163072
S184113
N159216
G0112149
EN183160
EM168329
EN232793
ENS277545
E0108691
E0115008
E37462
EN0775
E0100146
E7430
ENU653
E00168314
T197971
ENSG0
```

The same for the colum

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6 Sample7 Sample8 Sample9 Sample10    Sample11    Sample12
```

I want to have the clustering too and not trun off the clustring on the row

Comment: Can you please describe more clearly what your desired output is? What are the rownames in your data?

Comment: @Calum You please look above to see if it is clear now ?

Comment: What do you mean by clustering? Do you just want a chart where the rownames are on y axis, the column names are on x axis, and the colour of each cell represents the value?

Comment: @Calum You you know that heatmap uses a cluster function which link each row to another row. I want to know if it is possible to keep such a linkage when you plot it ?

Comment: Oh you mean you want to keep the row order but also keep the dendrogram (the branching diagram)? How would you expect that to look if the rows are not reordered? The only reason the dendrogram makes sense is because it reorders the rows so that similar rows are grouped together...

Comment: @Calum You OK, is it possible to somehow color the names in specific color (based on an order that I know) then I do the plot based on dendogram so that I can track them ? for example based on the `df` the first 5 row to be blue, the second 6 become green , the third 7 rows become red and the rest pink (just their name) .

Comment: Hmm I am not sure about colour. If you just need to keep track you could to this `rownames(df) <- stringr::str_c(1:nrow(df), ". ", rownames(df))` or something similar? Then you will know the original row number of every label even in the plot.

Comment: @Calum You please give a solution